# Quartz.net - should I manually delete a job scheduled for one-time execution?

Tags: quartz.net, quartz.net-3.0

I'm using `Quartz.NET 3` as a job scheduler in my application

Sometimes, I need to schedule a job for a "one time" immediate execution. At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
//Create job
var uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<MyJobClass>()
    .WithIdentity(uid, "ImmediateJobs")
    .Build();

//Create instant-activation trigger
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger-" + uid, "ImmediateJobsTriggers")
    .StartNow()
    .Build();

//Schedule job for execution
scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

My question is this: is this enough or does this cause possibile memory leaks? Should I somehow remove the job when finished or do any other cleanup operations? Or is it done automatically, since the job doesn't have any other triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading further the documentation, I found out you can trigger an existing job by using:

```
var jobKey = new JobKey(id, group);
scheduler.TriggerJob(jobKey);
```

without creating a new one each time.